# IApplication.Shutdown rights problem

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects, c#

In ArcGIS 10.1 using Add-In, IApplication.Shutdown works fine on my PC, but when I install it on other computer it give error, something like "Not enough rights to close the application". The difference is: my PC - Win8, other - Win7 + in the domain. My best guess was that it is due to lack of Administrative rights that add in can't close ArcMap. Is there any workaround?